# UI Automation trace templates are storing absolute paths

Tags: xcode, ios-ui-automation

I've started using UI Automation to write tests for our iOS app. I saved a .tracetemplate file and checked it into git. My coworker opened the template and tried to run the scripts, but got errors. He looked inside the file and found that it was storing absolute paths to my test scripts.

Is there any way to get UI Automation to save project-relative paths in .tracetemplate files?

Comment: In our UIAutomation tests, we don't check in the .tracetemplate files.  Can you say more about how you are saving/running your tests, and why the tracetemplate needs to be versioned?

Comment: They don't need to be *versioned* per se, but we do use git as a source code repository, i.e. a place to share code and collaborate. It would be nice if, after spending the time to put together a test template, I could just check it in so everyone on my team could have it. (Even without checking them in, sharing templates is difficult due to the absolute paths.) I gave up on finding a way to do this, and ending up writing shell scripts to run the tests.

Comment: I guess I'm not clear on what's being tested by your template. The more common use case of instruments is writing functional UIAutomation tests in javascript and versioning those.  Can you describe how you are using instruments?

Comment: That's exactly what we're doing. I hoped templates would be a good way to package a bunch of related tests together.

Comment: Aah, OK.  So it sounds like you're trying to split your tests into functional groups, instead of running them all at once.  Instruments doesn't really do that, but there are some test frameworks that offer this.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided that this isn't possible. Xcode and Instruments seem to be standalone applications. Instruments is for testing *apps* and really has no concept of an Xcode *project*. There is probably no way to tell Instruments to use paths that are relative to a project.

We achieved our goal of automating a set of UI tests by launching them from a shell script.